# UPPER function used in initialisation of an IN parameter not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE appraisal
  (p_grade IN VARCHAR2 := UPPER(' '))
IS
 v_appraisal VARCHAR2(20) := '';
BEGIN
 v_appraisal := CASE p_grade
     WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
     WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very good'
     WHEN 'C' THEN 'Bad'
     ELSE 'No such grade!'
     END;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grade:-'||p_grade ||' Appraisal:-'|| v_appraisal);
END;
/

EXECUTE appraisal('a');
```

Output:

```
Grade:-a Appraisal:-No such grade!"
```

I am wondering why is this not working - what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `a` and `A` aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: that is why i used the function to be in upper case in case i write in lower case

Comment: You didn't in fact do that. You set the default value to `UPPER(' ')` - whatever that means. That `UPPER` isn't going to be called if you provide a value.

Comment: Ok...and may i ask why?

Comment: Why should it? Why should the expression `UPPER(' ')` change something that's called `p_grade`? That would be completely confusing.

Comment: Remove the default from the parameter and use `CASE UPPER (p_grade)`.

Comment: Well, i don't know. I just expected when i call appraisal and pass parameter 'a' to the procedure, the expression UPPER(' ')  which is a function which in the end returns only one value that converts lowercase to uppercase to return the converted value and send it to variable p_grade to hold it for further processing. P.S: i have never programmed before, so i don't know anything and i don't know if i ever will...I have just started to embark new experiences...so sorry for annoying questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `UPPER()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/functions226.htm) does return the uppercase version of whatever is passed to it, but in your default clause you're passing the literal `' '`, which is a single space. Whitespace has no casing so there is no difference between lowercase space and uppercase space - the concept doesn't really make sense. You are *not* passing in the procedure's parameter value to that function.

[The defaut clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS666) is there to provide a default value if the caller doesn't supply one. So if you did `execute appraisal;` then within that procedure call the `p_grade` variable would have a value if a single space, which isn't helpful, and isn't what you want here. You don't really want a default at all.

As @DavidFaber said you need to get the uppercase equivalent of the parmeter value when you evaluate it, so you could do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE appraisal
  (p_grade IN VARCHAR2)
IS
 v_appraisal VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
 v_appraisal := CASE UPPER(p_grade)
     WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
     WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very good'
     WHEN 'C' THEN 'Bad'
     ELSE 'No such grade!'
     END;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grade:-'|| UPPER(p_grade)
  ||' Appraisal:-'|| v_appraisal);
END;
/
```

Alternativley you could declare a local variable that is set to the uppercase value and use that:

```
 v_grade varchar2(1) := UPPER(p_grade);
```

You shouldn't generally assume that whoever calls your procedure will display the `dbms_output` buffer. It's OK for debugging or experimenting where you have control of the calling environment, but not in real code, usually. You might actually want a function that returns the `v_appraisal` values, for example. [Here's an SQL Fiddle demo of a simole function version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0c2a5/1). Or just a look-up table that holds the grades and their descriptions.

Comment: What an excellent explanation, now it makes sense, thank you for your time in explaining it.